# python variable's "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python

I have a line of code that assigns a variable to an array, it looks something like this

```
var = self.data0.close[0]
```

this sits inside of a for loop with the 'data0' changing on each loop.  the issue the code should look like this:

```
var = 'self.%s.close[0]' % pair.data1
```

with the `%s` populating from `pair.data1` however i get an error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'self.data1.close[0]'
```

`self.data1.close[0]` is not a string, it is actually a pointer to an array.  How can I properly change the structure to get the "data0" to update.

maybe that issue here is I am using a string to define what is already a path to an array?

Comment: It looks like you want something like [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: thats it's exactly the problem.  that works. thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

```
>>> data0 = 12
>>> var = eval('data%s' % '0')
>>> var
12
```